# I'd like to know the meaning of 'oh~the heartache I found.'

Tags: meaning, word-order, lyrics, intensifiers

MY favorite song is 'I was looking for someone to love.'sung by Leif Garrett.

In the lyrics of the song, I found the phrase like 'I was looking for someone to love and oh the heartaches I found.'
I'd like to know the meaning of 'oh~the heartache I found.'

Maybe, I think it is the inversion of 'oh~ I found the heartache.'
Am I right?
Please, tell me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shortened way of saying,

> *Oh! You wouldn't believe how much heartache I found [when I was looking for someone to love]*

The interjection *oh* is this case serves as an intensifier to let the person know that whatever was found – in this case, heartache – was found in an extreme measure.

Another similar usage of the word *oh* can be found in a famous children's book by Dr. Seuss:

[image]

If the book was simply entitled "The Places You'll Go", it wouldn't have the same connotation. With the word *Oh* in front, the readers are clued in; it's almost as if the author is saying, "The *amazing* places you'll go," even with the adjective omitted.

Of course, without a specific adjective, the book could be talking about an extreme in either direction (such as, "The *awful* places you'll go").

Comment: I'm glad you found this answer helpful; however, you [accepted it way too fast](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).